# django inspectdb in admin site (admin.site.register)

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have been given a small legacy db (mysql) to work with, and therefore, I have tried to use the inspectdb command in django.

So, I use something like:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

It works fine, and I take the models.py and copy the class it created into my app (searchapp) as a models.py file.

I have done a syncdb, and everything went fine. Results are as expected.

Now, I have tried to add this model into my admin site, using:

```
from searchapp.models import Abaqus
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Abaqus)
```

stored in a file called admin.py (Abaqus is the name of the class generated by inspectdb and searchapp is the app name). However, I am not able to see the app on the admin site. I have checked my settings.py and it includes the 'searchapp'.

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect admin.py is not loaded. You could check this by putting a debug statement just above the `register` call:

```
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
admin.site.register(Abaqus)
```

If this is in fact the case, the correct way to ensure `admin.py` is loaded is to call `django.contrib.admin.autodiscover()` at the beginning of your main url conf.

If you've written no admin classes and don't want an `admin.py`, you can call `admin.site.register(Abaqus)` right below where the model is defined, inside models.py.

If you have an admin module structured like the following, `import admin` within models.py to ensure the code is run:

```
myapp
  |--models.py
  |--views.py
  |--admin
       |--__init__.py
       |--views.py
       |--base.py
```

Another possible cause would be that you are missing the permissions to edit the model.  Double check that you are logged in as a superuser.

Comment: oh wow.. thats right i.e including it directly in models.py Is this good practice tho?.. strange, but right :) Why does django do this? is this specfic to inspectdb outputs? Thanks again!

Comment: dokkaebi: Is it OK to use admin.site.register inside models.py?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why the admin app doesn't scrape through all installed apps and load the admin.py files.  I guess it doesn't, though, and if you never import admin elsewhere there's no reason it should be loaded. I don't know if it's common practice to import admin.py for this reason -- I just recommend commenting why you've done it so it isn't removed in the future.

Comment: Re: your second comment, it is fine to do it there.  That's where I register models for which I haven't written an Admin class.

Comment: Thanks dokkaebi a tonne.. Really helps! I guess sometimes things on strange on my Ubuntu x64. Not sure why!

Comment: You're supposed to have that admin include in urls.py.